# Not able to fetch exact phrase from the Twitter API in Spark Streaming application

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark

My operator is, happy weekend. I want exact phrase from the Twitter API. If I give it as "happy weekend", it takes same including double quotes.But I want excluding double quotes and exact phrase,

tweet: I wish you a happy weekend ---------> extracted by application
 tweet: I wish you a happy and healthy weekend--------->not extracted by application

Please assist me on the same.

I am using scala 2.9.3 and spark 0.7.3.

Thanks,
Reddi

Comment: Include the code you are using.

Comment: val stream = ssc.twitterStream(myConsumerKey, myConsumerSecret, myAccessToken, myTokenSecret, filters)

Comment: here, filter is: home security

Comment: I am expecting exact multiple keyword and exact order

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, per the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track), the track endpoint on the Streaming API does not support exact phrase matches.

> A phrase may be one or more terms separated by spaces, and a phrase will match if all of the terms in the phrase are present in the Tweet, regardless of order and ignoring case.

You'll have to do some additional filtering in your scala code.